# VSTS Load Test: single request by many users over time

Tags: azure-devops, load-testing

I have an end-point, let's call it https://www.ajax.org/api/v1/offers.

The scenario is that 80.000 users will access this end-point one time each, and they will all make this one request within 60 minutes.

How exactly do you model this in a VSTS Load Test?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ".webtest" that does the request.

The load of 80000 requests in one hour is about 1333 per minute, which is about 22 per second. (Check: 22 * 60 *60 = 79200 and 23 * 60 * 60 = 82800, so the 22 or 23 is about right.) If each request takes on average one second then will need 23 Virtual Users (VUs) to create the total load. If each request takes on average two seconds then would need about 46 VUs. (Check: (46 / 2) * 60 * 60 = 82800 and (45 /2) * 60 * 60 = 81000. So still about right.) Even though there is only one test must specify a test mix, so use "Test mix based on number of tests started".

Once the average request time is known when under load then its value can be used in the style above to set the required number of VUs.

Another approach starts with the above sums to find minimum numbers of VUs but uses a "Test mix based on user pace". Suppose we specify 100 VUs (which is normally considered a modest load). Then we need each VU to process 80000/100 = 800 webtests per hour and we just specify that 800 in the test mix window. -- On reflection this may be the better approach but I think the analysis above is useful.

To simulate 80000 **different** users ensure that the "Percentage of new users" is 100 in the scenario properties.

If you want exactly 80000 requests in the run then specify that as the "Number of iterations" in the "Run settings" along with "Use test iterations" set to "true". If you want about 80000 then I recommend setting "Use test iterations" to "false" and giving a "Run duration" of one hour.

Comment: Sigh, don't get it, please bear with me. Could you please sum up exactly how you would tell it to do exactly 80000 requests from different users spread out over the course of an hour? Thank you!

Comment: - could it be just setting 80000 test iterations with a constant user load of 1, and then setting percentage of new users to 100? And having selected the test with 1 request to the end-point in test mix?

Comment: - or 1 iteration with a constant user load of about 11.000, and then run this test every ten minutes over the course of an hour (giving 77.000 requests)? Would this have the 11.000 requests be made at the, more or less, exact same time?

Comment: @KimSchioett Please read the paragraph starting *"Another approach ..."* again. Set the user load to a constant 100. Set the test mix to "...user pace" with 800 per hour. So 100 users executing 800 tests each per hour is 800 * 100 = 80000.

Comment: Thanks, just discovered the "per hour"-field in the Test Mix :). If you do this, you'll have 100 distinct users requesting the end-point instead of 80000, right? If you then set percentage of new users to 100, you'll then have 80000 distinct user-requests, or?

Comment: I think you are beginning to understand my answer.

Comment: I would think so, too. Turns out that setting the percentage of new users to 100 deletes the cache for the particular user between requests, simulating a fresh request, cache-wise, which will probably be sufficient for the particular test.